# Prevent adding new rows in datagrid, If no values are added in a new row

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a datagrid in a WPF application, in which i allow the users to add new rows, but setting  CanUserAddRows="True". However, if i am in the new row and dont give any values in that row but click on tab till the focus moves of the last column in the new row then another blank row is added. If i keep clicking on tab multiple blank rows are added. How can i prevent this from happening? i.e, if the new row is blank, another new row should not be added. I have set CanUserDeleteRows="false".

I couldnt find any answers searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add validation in the RowEndEditing event and do a e.cancel from there if you found out the row is empty. You can use the e.Row property to determine the cell values from that function.