# Manually prevent new rows in WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid

Good day. How programmatically prevent the creation of new rows in data grid? For example:

```
private void SomeDataGridEvent()
   if (MyBoolConditionIsTrue())
      Prevent_Grid_Row_Creation_Logic
   else
     //Do Nothing. The new row is created
```

**Edit1:**
Note: CanUserDeleteRows must be TRUE. The user CAN add rows, but only if some condition is true.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent adding new rows in datagrid, If no values are added in a new row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25695456/prevent-adding-new-rows-in-datagrid-if-no-values-are-added-in-a-new-row)

Comment: You can simply set `CanUserAddRows="False"`

Comment: @Sinatr He specifically asked for programmaticall solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like that:

`AddingNewItem="DataGrid_AddingNewItem"`

```
private void DataGrid_AddingNewItem(object sender, AddingNewItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is DataGrid dg)
    {
        if (MyBoolConditionIsTrue())
        {
            dg.Items.Remove(e.NewItem);
        }
        else
        {
            //Do Nothing. The new row is created
        }
    }
}
```

Or

`RowEditEnding="DataGrid_RowEditEnding"`

```
private void DataGrid_RowEditEnding(object sender, DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
    if (MyBoolConditionIsTrue())
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
    else
    {
        //Do Nothing. The new row is created
    }
}
```

Comment: The correct answer is "DataGrid_RowEditEnding". Thanks!